# Into a collada 3d file, a p element is empty and maya can import it

Tags: opengl, model, 3d, maya, collada

I´m making my own collada parser, and found something I have never seen before, so I don´t know how to interpret.

I´m exporting a model I have in FBX to collada Dae. My problem is that now, the only "p" xml element  I found inside is empty and I don´t know to load the mesh without this tag.

The really funny thing is that Maya can import it without problems. Can anyone explain to me how to interpret a dae file with the empty p tag?

EDIT:

I thought it might be unindexed primitives. But, how data source is interpreted without indexes ? I´m asking this because the number of normal, positions and text coords differs in the accessor.

Comment: I thought it might be unindexed primitives. But, how data source is interpreted without indexes ?

Comment: While many of us would be happy to help answer your question, we are much more likely to understand the problem and provide a helpful answer if you show us the data you're actually parsing. Here's some info on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question.